# restrict the function input to be float32 NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, types

Is there a way to restrict the type of function input in python or I should always convert the input NumPy array to be float 32 array if I want?

I am trying to restrict the function input argument type to be a float 32 NumPy array. I have try something like below:

```
import numpy as np

def f(input : np.float32):
    return input*2
```

However, if I give an int NumPy array, the function is still work and return an int array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read more about Python Annotations here [PEP3107](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/).

Annotations doesn't force the function to accept input as the specified type.

Access annotations by,
`print(f.__annotations__)` in your case.

You can use `yourlist.astype(np.float32)` to force the list argument to be NumPy float32.

```
def f(input : np.float32)-> np.float32:
    return input.astype(np.float32)*2
```